# Inject shared ViewModel with Koin

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, koin

I have 4 different fragments and all fragments need to subscribe generic new topics. If this fragment removed; I need to ubsubscribe from last topics.
So I initialize this socket in MainActivity's SocketVM and other Fragments ViewModels inherited from SocketVM.

I can communicate between those ViewModels by using `by sharedViewModel()` in Fragments but I will need to subscribe all required LiveData in Fragments and Activity. To communicate between ViewModels I need to listen and post values in Fragment and Activity classes, this seems unclear to me.

How can I achieve this without putting so much code in Fragments and Activity.

Comment: Have your tried it? Could you please provide some code?

Comment: @ChristianB I've tried as single { SocketViewModel(get()) } instead of viewModel {}, also making them inherit from SocketViewModel, it helps nothing because in every fragment it creates new ViewModels with new created SocketViewModel